# Microsoft Graph SDK stopped working after v12

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I was using Microsoft Graph SDK v12 in my project and everything worked fine but after updating the NuGet package to v17, it stopped working. I am not getting any response to requests, it keeps on waiting.

I am using `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize` to authorize and then `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token` to get a token.

I am using the following code to create the `GraphServiceClient`

```cs
return new GraphServiceClient(new DelegateAuthenticationProvider((requestMessage) =>
{
    requestMessage
        .Headers
        .Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", DataHelper.AccessToken);

    return Task.FromResult(0);
}));
```

After that, I tried to access the Calendar using:

```cs
var op = graphClient
    .Me
    .CalendarGroups
    .Request()
    .GetAsync()
    .Result.Select(x => x)
    .ToList();
```

In v12 the same functions are working fine but in any version above v12, it's not working.

Is there any change in authentication or calling the API functions in the new versions?

Comment: What are you getting for an error/exception?

Comment: @MarcLaFleur There is no error/exception coming, It just keeps on waiting for the response.

Comment: Why are you using `.Select(x => x)`? What is the purpose of that pattern?

Comment: it is just an example, I can use this to map results to my models.

Answer (score 0):

The `GetAsync` method returns a Task, so you should await the call.

`//      \...../
var op = await graphClient
    .Me
    .CalendarGroups
    .Request()
    .GetAsync()
    .ToList();`

Comment: Your code isn't correct. When you use `.Result` you are getting the result of the underlying `Task`. Normally you would use `await` since `.Result` is blocking execution until the task completes but it isn't required. `Task<T>.Result` returns the same result as `await Task<t>`.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a deadlock because you are calling `.Result` in your application and I am going to guess you are calling `.Result` inside DataHelper.AccessToken.  This will fail when running in an application that uses a SyncronizationContext that is single threaded like WinForms or ASP.NET.

It worked before because of the order that these methods were called.  The DelegatedAuthProvider is now called in the request pipeline to enable incremental consent and to take advantage of the MSAL token cache.  This now causes an async method to be called from within an async method.  This will work in Console app because of the type of syncronization method, but it won't work in ASP.NET or WinForms.

You will need to make DataHelper.AccessToken a `async` method and `await` it resolve the problem.  Or you could use one of our new [AuthenticationProviders](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/choose-authentication-providers?tabs=CS) to resolve the issue.